# How can i display a clicked element of my array in React?

Tags: reactjs

So i have to realize a page in which an array of json elements is shown

(https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts)

and then if i click one of them the one i clicked is the only one that has to be displayed.

that is the code that i wrote

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './GetOnlinePosts.css';


class GetOnlinePosts extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        error: null,
        isLoaded: false,
        posts: [],

        clicked: false
    };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

handleClick(e) {
    let state = this.state

    this.setState({ clicked: !state.clicked })


}

handleReturn() {
    this.setState(state => ({
        clicked: false
    }));
    this.render()
}

componentDidMount() {

    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(
            // handle the result
            (result) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    posts: result
                });
            },

            // Handle error 
            (error) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoaded: true,
                    error
                })
            },
        )
}

render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, posts, clicked, } = this.state;

    if (error) {
        return <div>Error in loading</div>
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
        return <div>Loading ...</div>
    } else if (clicked) {
        for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
            if (this.state.clicked) {
                return (
                    <div className="selectedPostContainer">

                        <p className="title">User: {posts[i].userId}<br></br>{posts[i].title}</p>
                        <p className="body">Post ID: {posts[i].id}</p>
                        <br></br>
                        <p className="body">{posts[i].body}</p>

                    </div>

                )


            }
        }


    }
    else {
        return (
            <div className="postContainer">
                <ol className="item">
                    {
                        posts.map((post,i) => (
                            <li key={"Post" + post.id} onClick={this.handleClick} align="start">
                                <div>
                                    <p className="title">{post.title}</p>
                                    <p className="body">{post.body}</p>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        ))
                    }
                </ol>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

}


export default GetOnlinePosts;
```

i have tried to pass an id to identify the clicked element

```
 <li key={"Post" + post.id} onClick={this.handleClick(this)} align="start">
```

but it will automatically execute the function handleClick.

**so how can i save my element position to display the element when it is clicked?**

I have to admit that i am really really noob in react, plus i came from jquery where manipulating DOM was more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, I believe you misunderstood that every single list item has its own `clicked` state. In fact, the state belongs to the `GetOnlinePosts` component.

What you want to do is to save the clicked post Id to the state:

```
this.state = {
  error: null,
  isLoaded: false,
  posts: [],
  clickedId: null
};
```

When the `clickedId` is null(or falsy), you can set to display the whole list. Otherwise, filter the clicked post and display it. Here is the updated render method for your reference:

```
render() {
  const { error, isLoaded, posts, clickedId } = this.state;

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error in loading</div>;
  }

  if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading ...</div>;
  }

  if (clickedId) {
    const post = posts.filter(p => p.id === clickedId)[0];
    return (
      <div
        className="selectedPostContainer"
        onClick={() => this.handleClick(post.id)}
      >
        <p className="title">
          User: {post.userId}
          <br />
          {post.title}
        </p>
        <p className="body">Post ID: {post.id}</p>
        <br />
        <p className="body">{post.body}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="postContainer">
      <ol className="item">
        {posts.map((post, i) => (
          <li
            key={"Post" + post.id}
            onClick={() => this.handleClick(post.id)}
            align="start"
          >
            <div>
              <p className="title">{post.title}</p>
              <p className="body">{post.body}</p>
            </div>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ol>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And the onClick handler becomes:

```
handleClick(id) {
  let { clickedId } = this.state;
  if (clickedId) {
    this.setState({ clickedId: null });
  } else {
    this.setState({ clickedId: id });
  }
}
```

I created a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-can-i-display-a-clicked-element-of-my-array-in-react-3ne3n) that you can have a look.

You are doing great if you are new to React. Keep it up!

Comment: Thanks! i still don't get why is there a "0" as index in : const post = posts.filter(p => p.id === clickedId)[0];

Comment: Here I am just using the filter() method to find the post with matched Id. The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function. In this case, it will most likely to return an array with single element, the one with matched Id. You can also use the find() method: `const post = posts.find(p => p.id === clickedId);`

Answer (score 0):

if the function is executing immediately try changing this:

`onClick={this.handleClick(this)}`

to

`onClick={() => this.handleClick(this)}`